# How to get data for current month from different dates of data?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have attendance of users for all the months. Now i just want to fetch the data for current month only.

I searched the web and found out

> date('F Y');

returns the current month and year. But i don't know how do i use it for fetching the current month data

My Model Code is :

```
public function monthly_login()
 {

      $this->db->select('*');

      $this->db->from('daily_data2');

      $this->db->where('date_data', date('F Y'));

      $this->db->where('entry >','100');

      $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");

      $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');

      $query = $this->db->get();


       echo $this->db->last_query();
       $res   = $query->result();        

      return $res;

}
```

It returns this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`daily_data2`) INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`emp_id` = `daily_data2`.`emp_id` WHERE `date_data` = 'January 2016' AND `entry` > '100' ORDER BY `date_data` ASCarray(0) { }
```

Now in my database i have a field called data_data which has date in this way:

> 2015-11-04 13:29:32

So what should be my query that fetches only the data for current month.

Comment: Replace `$this->db->where('date_data', date('F Y'));` along with `$this->db->where('MONTH(date_data)', date('m'));`

Comment: Thanks @Uchiha it works

Comment: Using functions on data to suit a filtering condition is a terrible approach in SQL terms. So whilst this type of question has been answered many times before, it isn't necessarily the best answer that has been chosen.

Comment: @Uchiha How do i get the last month??

Comment: Thank you So much @Uchiha is there anything for week?

Comment: @Uchiha is this query correct ? 
          $this->db->where('MONTH(date_data)', date('Y-n-j',strtotime("")));

Comment: Nope for what you were querying it

Comment: i want to fetch records for last month and last week

Comment: How do i fetch the last last month records i mean the where condition should be where(month="December")..!!

Answer (score 5):

Please replace your function to below code :

```
public function monthly_login()
 {

      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('daily_data2');
      $this->db->where('MONTH(date_data)', date('m')); //For current month
      $this->db->where('YEAR(date_data)', date('Y')); // For current year
      $this->db->where('entry >','100');
      $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");
      $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');
      $query = $this->db->get();


       echo $this->db->last_query();
       $res   = $query->result();        
      return $res;

    }
```

Comment: you can also do this by `$this->db->where('MONTH(date_data)', MONTH(NOW());` a mysql approach

Comment: @DishaV. how to get last week ?? $this->db->where('WEEK(date_data)', WEEK(NOW());

Comment: or last month?? instead of current month

Comment: @DishaV. `$this->db->where('MONTH(date_data)', MONTH(NOW());` it should be `$this->db->where('MONTH(date_data)', MONTH(NOW()));` you missed the last `)`

Comment: @Uchiha is this query correct?
          $this->db->where('MONTH(date_data)', date('Y-n-j',strtotime("")));